org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with Java Selenium CI pipeline only on localhost URL
I have a React project with a Java Selenium e2e test suite in the same repo and I am using GitHub Actions for a CI pipeline to run the tests on push or PR to main. The tests all pass when I run them either on the deployed app on Render or running on localhost. The CI pipeline also works perfectly when tests are set to run on the deployed app but the CI pipeline tests won't connect when set to test the app running locally on localhost.
Projects2ColumnsTest > testPresenceOfBurgerBarMenu() FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
      (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=124.0.6367.60)
    Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
    System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.5.0-1018-azure', java.version: '17.0.11'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Command: [a1d60a462e51376719f65ce4cfea26e4, get {url=http://127.0.0.1:5173/}]
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome-headless-shell, browserVersion: 124.0.6367.60, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 124.0.6367.207 (a9001a6e39f..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:33853}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: linux, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:33853/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 124.0.6367.60, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}

I doubt the Java is very useful as the tests all run fine locally. The CI workflow is:
name: e2e automation tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Update Chrome to latest version
      run:  |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
        google-chrome --version

    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        distribution: 'adopt'
        java-version: '17'

    - name: Run e2e automation tests
      working-directory: e2e
      run: ./gradlew build

    - name: Upload Selenium screenshots
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      if: always()
      with:
        name: screenshots
        path: /home/runner/work/portfolio-react/portfolio-react/e2e/app/screenshots/

Please ask if any more details would be useful.
The same tests in the same situation all pass when run locally in terminal.
I have also tried changing the URL to 127.0.0.1 and even a local IP for my machine.
I can reach the site in Chrome for all URLs tried but each fails in the CI tests with the same error.
I am very new to Java, Selenium, CI and yaml.
